# Can't change widget color

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to change the background color of my widget but it's not working (color won't change) and I don't know why.

In my configuration activity I have a button to change the color, eg:

```
button_black_bg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                background_color_int = 0x000000;

                //set color in widget-preview
                widget_background_preview.setBackgroundColor(background_color_int | (background_opacity_int << 24));

            }
        });
```

A second button to change the opacity:

```
button_bg_alpha_50.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                background_opacity_int = 0x80;
                widget_background_preview.setBackgroundColor(background_color_int | (background_opacity_int << 24));

            }
        });
```

At last, the 'accept'-button:

```
    button_accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

                    if (extras != null) {
                        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
                    }

                    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_relative, "setBackgroundColor", background_color_int | (background_opacity_int << 24));

                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, remoteViews);

                Intent resultValue = new Intent();
                resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);

                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
                finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

A Widget is a `RemoteView`. You have very limited resource to update UI of a widget and you should not do it directly.

You can try something like this :

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                          R.layout.your_layout);
remoteViews.setInt(viewId, "setBackgroundColor", Color.BLACK);//this line for changing background colour
```

Change `Color.BLACK` to colour(an interger value) of your choice.